# Brief electron-positron pair creation annihilation and light deflection by gravity

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles

According to QFT there exists a non-vanishing probability amplitude for the following process:

- a photon very briefly turns into an electron-positron pair
- which then annihilate each other almost instantaneously, compatibly with the Uncertainty Principle, to give us back the original photon.

I am wondering, when this happens in a gravity field would the very briefly living electron-positron pair be subject to gravity? if yes, I imagine that somebody must have already tried to compute whether the resulting very slight deviation of trajectory is compatible with the observed curving of light rays predicted by General Relativity.

Comment: You are talking about loops in Feynman diagrams, so virtual particles. Those do not exist.

Comment: That is ok with me, but I was more interested to know the result of calculations for the case that the speculative assumption "yes, that pair of mass carrying particle are indeed exposed to gravity during their very brief existence" is taken for true. You know, just to see whether the result would be completely non-sense, or whether it may stimulate deeper reflections.

Comment: Assuming we had a QFT of gravity which could be perturbatively treated, yes, gravity would affect the (virtual) vaccum polarization processes. But its contribution is smaller than the direct bending of light by gravity at least by a factor of $\alpha \approx 1/137$

Comment: Another way to pose my question. Virtual particles, although not "real" do mediate the exchange of momentum, otherwise there would be no point to introduce them to explain the onset of let us say the electromagnetic force, the latter being very real. So, suppose the pair exists for a tiny interval $\tau$, I'd like to calculate the $\delta p$ they speculatively would gain when exposed to a gravity field $g$ (just intended in the classical way, without resorting to any QFT of gravity) during said $\tau$. While not worrying whether this makes any sense at all. Just want to get to a number.

Comment: You have elevated a shared metaphor to a misconception of a physical action. Gravity deflects energy and momentum, and a Feynman diagram conserves energy and momentum, despite your lies-to-children imagery. So any and all consistent calculations should not be able to distinguish your loop diagram from a tree diagram or a plain photon propagator.